# how to get 1 out of each duplicate elements on an array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, array-unique

My function store elements in an array like this:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Roger',
    'id' => '1',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'David',
    'id' => '2',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'David',
    'id' => '2',
  ),
)
```

I used array_unique($myArray), but it returns only the non-duplicate elements.

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Roger',
    'id' => '1',
  ),
)
```

I need 1 out of each duplicate elements.

Comment: I wouldn't store those names in a 2 dimensional array, if it is really your function, and it only needs to return names. A simpler 1 dimensional array would make more sense and in that case `array_unique()` will also work properly.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Doesnt actually store just names. stores some ids an some other things

Comment: OK, in that case please make your question reflect that. Also, if possible, use [var_export()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export) to create your question, that way we can use the code in your question to create an answer.

Comment: Updated the anwer. I dont know what you mean by "var_export() to create your question"

Comment: It seems you've used `var_dump()` to show us the content of your array. The output of `var_dump()` cannot be used as code. If you use `var_export()` instead you get proper code as output.

Comment: Updated. I hope that it's clearer now.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Doesn't that look better? One final question. Does all the content in one sub-array have to be unique, or can we only look at the names and make those unique in the assumption that the rest will be unique? This makes me think, does the function that returns this 2D array contain a database query? Because it would be much easier to assure that the query only returns unique results than it is to make the results unique afterwards in PHP.

Comment: It does look way better! Answering your question, I need the id to be unique, it doesnt matter if two elements share the same name if they have different id's. Right now I cant change the query so it needs to be done afterwards.

Comment: OK, unique id only, that's clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not too difficult and can be solved with basic PHP. Assume that your data is stored in the variable `$rows` then you can do this:

```
$output = [];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
   $output[$row['id']] = $row;
}
```

The result will be in `$output`. For a live demo see: https://3v4l.org/B8FUK

In case you want normalize keys you can do:

```
$output = array_values($output);
```

Comment: @SOUserNumber613: You're welcome. Sorry I put you through all that for such a simple answer.